# Concourse CI - increasing shared memory of task containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, concourse

Is there anyway to increase `dev/shm` size of a task's container on concourse?

The `dev/shm` is defaulted to 64M which can't run my protractor tests properly as it requires more memory inside the container. I have been looking up the documentation and I haven't seen anything related to increasing shared memory size of a container.

Comment: How is your Concourse deployed?

There shouldn't be a limit on the size of a task's container.

Comment: Is there any way to use protractor without this this shared memory?

Comment: Yeah I found out that there is no limit on the task container which is a good thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved where shared memory is not in a task container